# rails , devise omniauth, multiple app_id ,app_secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

How to manage different APP_id,APP_KEY, in Devise.rb . using Devise omniauth with for multiple subdomains?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To split between development and production?

Comment: not for spliting environments,i have different sub domains(http://cisco.lvh.me.com,http://productleadership.lvh.me.com),I have created different apps for every subdomains in facebook also. have to manage different APP_KEY & APP_ID in the devise.rb file. or can u tell me how to manage these keys...?

Comment: This seems a bit hard... you can't relly on devise.rb because it is loaded on the server start, I think the path is create a method that gets request.domain and set the key in devise properly. However, I'm unsure of how to set devise secrets on the fly.

Comment: Another approach would be to start a different app for each one of the subdomains, if they are different apps, then it may make sense to do that.

Comment: When I had a simillar situation, I created a single app. Twitter and Facebook has provision to let your app make calls from any subdomains (of the same domain). But in this case, on authentication you wont be redirected to the same subdomain from where the request started. Can elaborate if required.

Comment: @manoj can u please brief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating facebook application for your application, fill in the details as shown below

```
BASIC INFO:
Display Name: ...
Namespace: ...
Contact Email: ..
App Domains: www.yourdomain.com yourdomain.com 

Website with Facebook Login:
Site URL: http://www.yourdomain.com
```

yourdomain.com in the 'App Domain' field will include all subdomains except www (As it is a special subdomain, so you have to explicitly specify that)

Use the app_id/secret as usual. This will let your application to communicate to facebook for authentication from any subdomain (*.yourdomain.com and www.yourdomain.com).

One small catch is that, when the user tries to login via facebook from A.yourdomain.com. On successfull login by the user in facebook, he will be redirected to http://www.yourdomain.com/users/auth/facebook (what you have given in the 'Site URL' field) rather than A.yourdomain.com/users/auth/facebook

So when redirecting from the OmniauthCallbacksController, you can redirect to the appropriate subdomain.